# Database modeling this relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, schema

Rails app:

1. A user has_many positions.
2. Each position has one company (company name and company id) per the following schema:

   ```
   create_table "positions", :force => true do |t|
     t.integer  "user_id"
     ...
     t.string   "company"
     t.integer  "company_id"
   end
   ```
3. I would like users to be able to "follow" as many individual companies as they would like (i.e. a user can follow many different companies a company can be followed by many different users). It would seem that this calls for a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between users and positions, but I want users to be able to follow the company *attribute* of a position row and not the position itself.

Should I create a new "following" table altogether that would pull companies from the positions table to be matched to user_id's? Or is there a way I can set up a has_many :through relationship and map user_id's to company_id's?

Thank you!

Comment: "how do i safely extract the company column from my positions table and preserve the position/company relationships?". Just create a new table called company with the 'company_id' and 'company' columns in it. And then simply remove the company column from the 'Positions' table.

Comment: ok but all else that i need is the position id as well. is there a straightforward low -risk way around this?

Comment: Add a column for position_id and create a dbs sequence for it. Write a tiny script or a procedure to populate it from sequence. Then once it fully populated, add constraint for it to be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I broadly agree with MickJ, although having created the Company and User models/tables (which obviously have an id column in each) I'd do it as:

```
create_table "companies" do |t|
   t.string "name"
   ... 
end

create_table "positions" do |t|
   t.references "user"
   t.references "company"
   ...
end

create_table "followings" do |t|
   t.references "user"
   t.references "company"
   ...
end
```

Models:

```
class User
  has_many :positions
  has_many :followings
end 

class Company
  has_many :positions
  has_many :followings
end 

class Position
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end 

class Following
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end
```

You could reference the company from the position by doing:

```
position = Position.first
puts position.company.name
```

or by user with something like

```
user = User.first
user.positions.each do |position| 
  puts position.company.name
end
```

-- EDIT1:

To extract the company name from positions into a separate table you'd be best off writing a little rake task - something like:

```
Position.all.each do |position|
  company = Company.find_or_initialize_by_name(position.company_name)
  position.company_id = company.id
  position.save
end
```

Then you might want to write a migration to remove the company name column from the positions table ... just to keep things tidy.

Comment: thanks guys. how do i safely extract the company column from my positions table and preserve the position/company relationships?

Comment: ... I've added a bit of code to the bottom of the answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you could have

A **User** table:

```
integer User_Id
....
```

A **Company** Table:

```
string company
integer company_id
...
```

A **Positions** table:

```
integer user_id foreign_key -> User table
integer company_id foreign_key -> company table
```

A **Following** table (If the user can follow any comapny regarding of whether he has a position in it):

```
integer user_id foreign_key -> User table
integer company_id foreign_key -> company table
```

**OR** if the user can only follow a company that he has position in then you can add a **new column to position table**. This would be a boolean flag telling if the user if 'following' the company identified by the position. Alternatively the Following table can also map user to position in this case.

Comment: a user can follow any company (not just a company he/she has worked at [is in their respective position table row]). if my current data model does have a company column in the positions table, how do i extract that safely and keep the connection with a has_one relationship between position and company?

Comment: If more than one person can have a position in the same company, then you have a bad database design at your hand in my opinion. The position table in this case should only contain the key identified of the company not the entire company details(company_id and company_name like you have). It would help you could edit your question bit to show more of your current schema/data model. I would be able to better help you then.